# Can I load HTML on Ghost.py

Tags: python, ghost.py

Can I load HTML on Ghost.py ,

If I use BeautifulSoup get the HTML code , how to load it on Ghost.py .

I try but not success, :

```
    from ghost import Ghost()
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    page = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org")
    html = BeautifulSoup(page)
    g = Ghost()
    with g.start() as session:
       page, resources = session.open(html)
```

Thank you for help .

Comment: `session.open("http://en.wikipedia.org")`

Comment: Lol, my bad. Ignore that last comment. Needed a vent.

Comment: Thank you for reply , but if I olny want load to code from BS , do you know how to do it ?

Comment: There's a number of problems with your code; you shouldn't be importing `Ghost()`, and there's no `request` in `urllib`. Otherwise, using the URL in `session.open` as @JoranBeasley suggests looks like it could be the answer. Then again, I've only got timeouts and segfaults so far...

Comment: I solved this problem :
import requests
s = requests.session()
s.post(URL, data=data, headers=header)
r = s.post(URL, data=, headers=header)
c_file = open('a.html', 'w')
for html in r.text:
 c_file.write(html)
c_file.close()